# Combine two Private Sub Worksheet_Changes

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to combine the following 2 codes. Any help would be appreciated

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim C As Range
  If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  For Each C In Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D:D")).Cells
    If C.Text = "y" Then
      C.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Shipped").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow
      C.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
  Next
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column <> 8 Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Dim SortRange As Range
    Set SortRange = Range(("A1"), Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp))
           SortRange.Sort Key1:=Range("H2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Comment: What part of that task are you having trouble with?

Comment: Any reason you can't just remove the End Sub from the first and the header from the second?

Answer (score 1):

### ?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim C As Range, SortRange as Range
  If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
      For Each C In Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D:D")).Cells
        If C.Text = "y" Then
          C.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Shipped").Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow
          C.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
      Next
  End If
'End Sub

'Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = 8 And Target.Cells.Count <= 1 Then
    Set SortRange = Range(("A1"), Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp))
    SortRange.Sort Key1:=Range("H2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
  End If
End Sub
```

---

**Instead of existing the `Sub` with your `If Statements`, they codes will only run if the opposite of your original `If Statements` are true. I also commented out the `Sub` declaration statement of the second `Sub` and the `End Sub` of the first `Sub`. Is this what you wanted?**